# Trying to combine 2 columns in sql query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, COUNT(*) AS TotalSentLast180Days
FROM (
        SELECT s.SubscriberKey
        FROM ENT._Sent s
            INNER JOIN ENT.AllSubscribershistroyland ROCS
                ON ROCS.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
        WHERE ROCS.SLSegment__c = 'S4 - real-love' 
        AND 'S6 - real-love'
        AND s.OYBAccountID = '85208879'
        AND s.EventDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -180, GETDATE())
    ) t
GROUP BY SubscriberKey
```

So in the " **AllSubscribershistroyland** " their are 2 columns that are called '**S4 - Dutch real-love'** and **'S6 - real-love**'. Im trying to run the query to see how many subscribers are in those 2 columns. I cant seem to combine them but when i run the query for example with one column i do get a result back. I tried the ' **AND '** to combine the 2  columns but i get an error code of "

> Error saving the Query field. An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.** "

if anyone can help me i would be very grateful

Comment: AND 'S6 - real-love' ?? what;s happening here? ROCS.SLSegment__c cant be both = 'S4 - real-love' AND 'S6 - real-love' perhaps an OR?

Comment: Well the error is about this `ROCS.SLSegment__c = 'S4 - real-love'  AND 'S6 - real-love'` you have to use the column name in both like `ROCS.SLSegment__c = 'S4 - real-love' 
AND ROCS.SLSegment__c = 'S6 - real-love'` **But the AND should be an OR in your case** as @P.Salmon suggested

Comment: " S6 real love" is a show that is stored in SLSegment__c table. im trying to see how many people are watching that show AND also the 'S4 - real-love " show.

Comment: But I assume that the table `ROCS.SLSegment__c` contains ONE thing the subscriber has viewed, so an AND will not work, as one column in one row cannot be both things. In fact you need a completely different query to satify that requirement

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what (R)DBMS are you really using? Please [edit] your question to (re)tag the appropriate one.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Btw, whehre is the connection to jquery? I cannot see any Javascript code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you very much for your help. I used the OR ROCS.SLSegment__c = 'S6 - real-love and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but if you are just trying to include both of your titles in the where clause for the same column then you could use the IN Clause:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, COUNT(*) AS TotalSentLast180Days
FROM (
        SELECT s.SubscriberKey
        FROM ENT._Sent s
            INNER JOIN ENT.AllSubscribershistroyland ROCS
                ON ROCS.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
        WHERE ROCS.SLSegment__c in ('S4 - real-love', 'S6 - real-love')
        AND s.OYBAccountID = '85208879'
        AND s.EventDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -180, GETDATE())
    ) t
GROUP BY SubscriberKey
```